# CS problem, turned to mathematics

Tags: number-theory, project-euler, decimal-expansion

I am trying to solve some of the projecteuler problems using a much of a programmers approach. However, I would like to get more into the math, and therefore would try to do some mathematical reasoning to this specific projecteuler exercise:

Surprisingly there are only three numbers that can be written as the sum of fourth
    powers of their digits:

$ 1634 = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 $

$ 8208 = 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4 $

$ 9474 = 9^4 + 4^4 + 7^4 + 4^4$

As $ 1=1^4$
   is not a sum it is not included.

The sum of these numbers is 1634 + 8208 + 9474 = 19316.

Find the sum of all the numbers that can be written as the sum of fifth powers of their
    digits.

---

There are various ways of presenting a reasonable solution to this problem, using simple programming skills. However, I would like to be able to do the reasoning on pen and paper and not rely on the computational power. Can anybody tell me the steps of how to solve this problem with mathematical reasoning?

Comment: Though I'm happy you're interested in the mathematics of these problems, I'm not sure project Euler problems should be discussed here since people actively work on these and they are kind of contest problems. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jeremy: I wouldn't worry too much in this case. This is a simple problem and the OP is asking for a very hard way of solving it, I doubt it will take much away from those on Project Euler.

Comment: I am a bit ambivalent. I think the question justifies as any other question on the board. Also, I am not asking for the result, but about the mathematical reasoning. If anybody who are doing the projecteuler exercises and are in search of material regarding a specific question, a discussion about the question would be more helpful and educational, than actually spoiling and ruining the question.

Comment: If there are $n$ digits, the average 5th power must be between $\frac 1n10^{n-1}$ and $\frac1n10^n$. This gives you that $n\le 6$. If no digit $>6$ occurs, you have $n\le 5$ (because $6\cdot 6^5<10^5$) and if a digit $>6$ occurs, you have $n\ge 5$ (because $7^5>10^4$). Since $d^5\equiv d\pmod{10}$, the sum of all but the last digit must be a multiple of $10$. This reduces the search space a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If a number $n$ has seven digits, the sum of fifth powers of digits is $\le 7\cdot 9^5<10^6\le n$ and with each additional digit the upper limit for the  power-sum grows by at most $9^5$ whereas the lower lmit for $n$ grows by a factor of $10$. We conclude that $n$ has at most six digits.

Moreover, from $d^5\equiv d\pmod{10}$ we see that the sum of all but the last digit must be a multiple of $10$.

We not that $a<b$ implies $a^5+b^5<(a+1)^5+(b-1)^5$, i.e. a sum of fifth powers for a given sum of digits is maximized when the digits are as close togethre as possible (i.e. assume at most tow consecutive values).

From $6\cdot 9^5=354294$, we conclude that $n$

- has at most five digits (see below)
- or has leading digits $3$, $\le5$ and then at most four $9$s (contradiction: $4\cdot 9^5+5^5+3^5<350000$)
- or has leading digit $2$ and at most five nines, so $n\le 2^5+6\cdot 9^5=295277$. In fact from $2+4\cdot 9=38$, we conclude that the sum of the five leading digits is at most $30$ and thus $n\le 2^5+4\cdot 7^5+9^5=126309<200000$, so this case is not possible either
- or has leading digit $1$ and at most five nines. Like above the sum of the first five digits is a multiple of $10$, so either $=30$ or $\le 20$. In the latter case we get $n\le1^5+3\cdot 5^5+4^5+9^5=69449<10000$. Remains the case with digit sum $30$. Dropping the leading $1$, the sum $29$ can be obtained with four digits as: $9+9+9+2, 9+9+8+3, 9+9+7+4, 9+9+6+5,9+8+8+4,9+8+7+5,9+7+7+6,8+8+8+5,8+8+7+6, 8+7+7+7$. For each of these ten cases one can compute the sum of fifth powers of these digits and the leading $1$ and add $0^9,\ldots ,9^9$ for the last digit to check if a valid number occurs. - Only one solution is found this way

For the five-digit (or less) case a lot of more case distinctions are necessary, though much can still be gained from the condition that the sum of all but th elast digit is a multiple of ten.
However, just learning from above the limit that $n<200000$ and then making a brute-force search, is probably the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to do the reasoning on pen and paper and not rely on the computational power. Can anybody tell me the steps of how to solve this problem with mathematical reasoning?

For a problem of this type it is hard to guess if that is possible without first performing the computer search up to a proven upper bound on the solutions.   If a search showed that there were a large number of solutions up to that bound, it would suggest that hand calculations and formal proofs could become complicated.

Sometimes the solution set has special structure that can be used in a theoretical solution, but this cannot always be seen before giving the problem to a computer.

Experiment usually precedes theory, and more so for number-theoretic problems where intuition is limited.